# OpenGL ESを用いた3D表示のプログラムの実行がうまく表示されません

Tags: java, opengl-es

今回の質問で一番教えてもらいたいことは、どこがどのようになっているため描画させたい図が表示されないのか、またどう改善させればよいのかという点です。

今2つの正六面体を描画するプログラム( Zバッファを有効にしたもの)を Android 端末で表示させる課題を進めています。
教科書としてオライリー・ジャパンの初めての OpenGL ES を用いて行われているのですが、教科書を読んだ末、次のようなプログラムリストにしてみました。ですが実際に動かしてみると起動後、画面は真っ青なまま3Dで表示させたい物体はでてきません。どのように変更すればよろしいでしょうか？とても勉強不足で正直何しているのかと思われるようなプログラムかとは思いますが何か助言をもらえないでしょうか？

一つ前に私はこの課題に似たZバッファを有効にしない課題を質問させていただいたのですがその分はしっかり実行までいきつくことができました。そしてその有効にしないプログラムから

```
//! 深度バッファを有効にする
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
```

をonSurfaceChanged内に組み込むことでZバッファを有効にした描画が可能になるというように書かれていてそのように変更し実行した結果先ほど述べたような結果が現れてしまったのです。

```
package com.example.rokumen1;

import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.os.Bundle;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import android.opengl.GLU;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView.Renderer;

import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL11;

public class rokumen1 extends Activity {

// ! 描写対象のView
private GLSurfaceView glSurfaceView = null;

/**
 * Called when the activity is first created.
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    glSurfaceView = new GLSurfaceView(this);
    glSurfaceView.setRenderer(new  GLRenderSample2());
    setContentView(glSurfaceView);
}

// ! Activity 休止時の処理
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    glSurfaceView.onPause();
}

// ! Activity復帰時の処理
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    glSurfaceView.onResume();
}

class GLRenderSample1 implements Renderer {
    float aspect=0.0f;
    int vertices=0;
    int indices=0;
    int  indicesLength=0;

    class Object3D {
        public float posX = 0.0f;
        public float posY = 0.0f;
        public float posZ = 0.0f;
        public float rotateY = 0.0f;
        public float scale = 1.0f;

        public float colR = 1.0f;
        public float colG = 1.0f;
        public float colB = 1.0f;
        public float colA = 1.0f;

        public void drawBox(GL10 gl) {
            //! 行列をデフォルト状態へ戻す
            gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
            gl.glLoadIdentity();

            //! 指定行列を生成
            gl.glTranslatef(posX, posY, posZ);
            gl.glRotatef(rotateY, 0, 1, 0);
            gl.glScalef(scale, scale, scale);

            //! 色指定
            gl.glColor4f(colR, colG, colB, colA);

            GL11 gl11 = (GL11) gl;
            //!頂点バッファの関連付け
            gl11.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, indicesLength, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
        }
    }

    Object3D box0 = new Object3D();
    Object3D box1 = new Object3D();


    // ! サーフェイス作成時の処理
    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig eglconfig) {
        //  Toast.makeText(OpenGLSample_1_2.this, "message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
        aspect = (float) width / (float) height;
        gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

        //! 深度バッファを有効にする
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);

        //! バッファを生成
        GL11 gl11 = (GL11) gl;
        {
            int[] buffer = new int[2];
            gl11.glGenBuffers(2, buffer, 0);

            vertices = buffer[0];
            indices = buffer[1];
        }
        //! 頂点バッファを作成する
        // ! 頂点転送
        {
            final float one = 1.0f;

            final float[] vertices = new float[]{
                    //! x y z
                    one,one,one, //!< 0 左上手前
                    one,one,-one, //!< 1 左上奥
                    -one,one,one, //!< 2 右上手前
                    -one,one,-one, //!<3 右上奥
                    one,-one,one, //!<4 左下手前
                    one,-one,-one, //!<5 左下奥
                    -one,-one,one, //!<6 右下手前
                    -one,-one,-one, //!<7 右下奥
            };

            FloatBuffer fb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4)
                    .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
            fb.put(vertices);
            fb.position(0);

            gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
            gl11.glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this.vertices);
            gl11.glBufferData(GL11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, fb.capacity() * 4, fb, GL11.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
            gl11.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);
        }
        // ! インデックスバッファ生成
        {
            final byte[] indices = new byte[]{
                    0,1,2,
                    2,1,3,
                    2,3,6,
                    6,3,7,
                    6,7,4,
                    4,7,5,
                    4,5,0,
                    0,5,1,
                    1,5,3,
                    3,5,7,
                    0,2,4,
                    4,2,6,
            };
            ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(indices.length)
                    .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
            bb.put(indices);
            indicesLength = bb.capacity();

            bb.position(0);

            gl11.glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, this.indices);
            gl11.glBufferData(GL11.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, bb.capacity(), bb, GL11.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f);
        gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        //! カメラ転送
        {
            gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
            gl.glLoadIdentity();

            GLU.gluPerspective(gl, 45.0f, aspect, 0.01f, 100.0f);
            GLU.gluLookAt(gl, 0, 5.0f, 5.0f, 0, 0, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        }

        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);

        {
            box0.posX = -0.5f;
            box0.rotateY += 1.0f;
            box0.colR = 1.0f;
            box0.colG = 0.0f;
            box0.colB = 1.0f;
            box0.drawBox(gl);
        }
        {
            box1.posX = 0.5f;
            box1.rotateY -= 0.5f;
            box1.colR = 0.0f;
            box1.colG = 0.0f;
            box1.colB = 1.0f;

            box1.drawBox(gl);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: 該当ソースコードをそのまま張られていますが、それなりの分量で問題の絞り込みも困難です（問題の丸投げにもみえてしまいます）。例えば、期待通り動いていた時のコードをベースに、そこから試してみようとおもったこと（期待する動作）、実際に変更を加えたソースコード箇所、などを明確にされるとより良くなると思います。

Comment: @yohjp
すみません、2つの正六面体を描画するプログラム( Zバッファを有効にしたもの)を一応参考にしている本の指示通り(本と言われても読んでないからわからないと思われるかもしれませんが・・・)に打ったものが上のプログラムなのですが自分が理解し間違っているせいかうまく実行できなかったのです。そこでなにか助言がもらえないかと思い今回質問させてもらったのですがどうでしょうか？一応Zバッファを利用しない状態で実行できた分からどのように変更したか編集して書き直しています。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zバッファをクリアしていないためではないでしょうか。

以下の行を

```
gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

以下のように変更してみてください。

```
gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```